# Проблема с размером фрейма

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Пишу программку, в которой активное меню привязано к низу устройства и скрывается. По сколько в iPhone 5 и других моделей разные конечные координаты привязываю все на вычисления... Очевидно ведь... Но тут беда... iPhone 4s, с первого раза, не хочет высчитывать высоту экрана. С начала он говорит, что его экран, как у 5го **View: 548.0**, кнопки, что б активировать меню естественно нет на экране... Сделал для окна координаты Y=0 получаю кнопку и меню, клик, оно становиться на место, еще клик, кнопка отображается как положено в низу. При этом iPhone 4 понимает уже что он 4й...

Кто сталкивался с такой едой, подскажите...

Вот как я высчитываю размеры и привязываю к низу.

```
_ButtonView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/3, self.view.frame.size.height - _ButtonView.frame.size.height, _ButtonView.frame.size.width, _ButtonView.frame.size.height);
```

А вот что пишет NSLog 4s

```
2013-05-13 16:15:20.963 ***[1008:907] View: 548.000000
2013-05-13 16:15:20.965 ***[1008:907] Frame: 105.000000
2013-05-13 16:15:23.910 ***[1008:907] View: 460.000000
2013-05-13 16:15:23.912 ***[1008:907] Frame: 105.000000
2013-05-13 16:15:25.781 ***[1008:907] View: 460.000000
2013-05-13 16:15:25.783 ***[1008:907] Frame: 105.000000
```

**self.view.frame.size.width/3** - Ставлю на середину экрана.

**self.view.frame.size.height - _ButtonView.frame.size.height** - От размера экрана отнимаю нужный мне фрейм и получаю его в низу экрана.

P.S. Размеры экрана не трогал.
P.S.S. Проект чистил, программу удалял и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте оперировать не размером вьюхи, а размером экрана

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]
```

Comment: Да, большес спасибо. Баг пофикшен... Вы случайно не в курсе чем может быть вызван такой сбой ?

Comment: Так сходу не скажу, нужно смотреть весь код.

Возможно вьюха не авторесайзится (и грузится из ксиба или сториборда) и ее реальный размер равен размеру пятого айфона.

Comment: Я работаю с XIB, но на 2х предыдущих окнах все было в порядке =( 
В Xib задан размер 5го iPhone но все на резинках...

Comment: Я просто предположил, не факт что я прав, зачит где-то закралась маленькая ошибка :)